# How can I upload image to the database using react hooks, redux?

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

How can upload image using redux and react-hooks?

1. Im already create handler for input[e.target.name]: e.target.value but I want to add
   create a handler for image but It cant recognize if it is file or not?

   ```
   const onChange = e => {

    const imageFile = e.target.files[0]
    console.log(imageFile)

    setPetData({ ...petData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

   }
   ```
2. With my input file petImage

   onChange(e) } 
         />

   ```
        <span className="file-icon">
           <i className="fas fa-upload"></i>
        </span>

        <span className="file-label">
          Upload Image
        </span>

      </span>

      <span className="file-name">
         {petImage}
      </span>
   ```
3. My Declaration on top with the using redux action **[petRegister]**

   import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'

   import PropTypes from "prop-types";

   import  { connect }  from 'react-redux'

   import { petRegister } from '../../actions/petActions'

Can I **add another handler for file like e.target.files[0]** ?

Thank you very much?